# find a combination which has the minimum value of standard deviation

Tags: python, combinations, minimize

110 choose 108 is so fast, but 522 choose 108 waste time to do so. Any Help?

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#read df
df = pd.read_csv('capacity.csv', header=None)
#plot df
df[1].hist()
plt.ylabel('Quantity')
plt.xlabel('Capacity / Ah')
plt.savefig('capacity_hist.png')
#numpy.ndarray is quicker than pandas.DataFrame here.
nda = df[1].values
# 110 choose 108 and find the best combinations
nda = nda[:111]
combin = combinations(nda, 108)
the_best_list = []
num = 0
tmp = nda.std()
for i in combin:
    num += 1
    if np.std(i) < tmp:
        tmp = np.std(i)
        the_best_list = i
#shows the result
print(num)
print(tmp)
print(the_best_list)
```

The shape of df is (522, 2).

The figure of hist of df is shown below:
[normal disbution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHMtH.png)

The file `capacity.csv` is shown below:

1,38.913
2,38.904
3,38.925
4,38.872
6,38.876
7,38.968
8,38.896
9,38.893
10,38.915
11,38.974
12,38.885
13,38.982
14,38.944
16,38.844
18,38.914
19,38.913
20,38.824
21,38.926
22,38.964
23,37.295
24,38.807
25,38.908
27,38.927
28,38.83
30,38.943
32,39.013
33,38.751
36,38.92
37,38.869
38,38.909
39,38.9
40,38.892
41,38.9
42,38.951
43,38.726
44,38.937
45,38.757
46,38.867
47,38.882
48,38.952
49,38.918
50,38.875
51,38.998
52,38.888
54,37.822
56,38.982
57,38.922
58,38.934
59,38.938
60,39.035
61,38.955
63,38.935
64,38.946
66,38.983
67,38.983
69,38.886
71,38.884
72,38.964
73,39.06
74,38.869
75,38.926
76,38.972
78,38.851
79,38.989
80,38.902
81,38.998
82,38.897
83,38.98
85,37.939
86,38.947
87,38.617
89,38.981
90,38.957
91,38.851
92,38.978
93,38.831
94,39.001
95,38.942
96,39.003
97,38.978
98,38.915
99,38.872
100,38.977
101,38.932
102,38.583
103,38.966
104,38.935
105,38.906
106,39.004
107,38.989
109,38.852
110,38.925
111,38.183
113,38.896
114,38.979
116,38.914
117,38.666
119,38.9
120,38.952
121,38.806
122,37.957
123,38.922
124,38.844
125,38.786
126,38.95
128,38.875
129,38.954
130,38.912
131,38.93
132,37.785
133,38.883
134,38.911
135,38.859
136,38.802
137,38.909
138,38.892
139,37.872
140,38.897
141,38.985
142,39
143,38.916
144,38.902
145,38.906
146,37.863
147,38.905
148,38.733
149,38.9
150,38.851
151,38.9
152,38.855
153,38.931
155,38.924
156,38.864
157,38.869
158,38.943
159,38.978
160,39.018
161,38.992
162,38.654
163,38.95
164,38.887
165,38.966
166,38.98
167,38.862
168,38.96
170,38.893
171,38.931
172,38.894
173,38.985
174,38.941
175,38.92
176,38.911
178,38.952
179,38.711
183,38.945
184,38.893
185,38.882
186,38.807
187,38.968
188,38.958
189,38.88
190,38.937
191,38.899
192,38.922
193,36.259
194,38.901
195,38.946
196,38.971
197,38.916
198,38.968
201,38.888
203,38.872
204,38.815
205,38.861
206,38.909
207,39.023
208,38.832
209,38.959
210,38.964
211,38.91
212,38.952
213,39.033
214,38.987
215,38.942
216,38.956
217,38.916
218,38.842
219,37.471
220,38.931
221,38.833
222,38.952
223,38.903
224,38.95
225,38.921
226,38.904
227,39.018
228,38.936
230,38.974
231,38.909
232,38.911
233,38.964
235,37.851
236,38.919
237,38.955
238,39.091
239,38.955
241,38.995
242,39.053
243,39.014
244,39.047
246,39.05
247,39.039
248,39.106
249,38.976
250,38.998
251,38.997
252,38.978
253,39.009
254,39.06
256,39.051
257,39.081
258,39.005
259,39.067
260,38.988
261,39.015
262,39.007
264,36.393
266,39.023
269,38.967
270,39.053
271,39.084
272,38.999
273,39.043
274,39.079
275,38.985
276,39.074
278,39.009
279,39.041
280,39.011
281,39.157
282,39.156
283,41.513
284,38.983
285,39.057
286,38.99
287,39.202
289,38.918
290,39.119
291,38.798
292,39.046
293,39.053
294,38.809
295,39.006
296,38.809
297,38.946
298,38.992
299,38.934
300,39.008
301,39.038
302,39.084
303,39.175
304,39.091
305,38.959
306,39.086
307,39.094
308,38.636
310,39.027
311,38.998
313,39.041
314,39.013
315,39.222
316,39.02
317,38.778
318,38.851
319,39.023
320,39.152
321,39.024
322,38.895
323,38.311
324,38.962
325,38.886
326,39.058
327,39.049
328,38.726
329,39.187
330,39.041
332,39.016
333,38.968
334,38.759
335,39.073
336,38.869
337,38.945
338,38.91
339,39.006
340,39.212
341,39.134
343,39.06
344,38.966
345,39.154
346,38.901
347,38.808
348,38.69
349,38.904
350,39.197
351,39.032
352,38.927
353,39.04
355,39.001
356,38.988
357,38.874
358,38.824
359,37.72
360,38.87
361,37.871
362,38.676
363,39.026
364,37.98
365,37.84
366,38.88
367,39.113
368,39.124
369,39.139
370,39.127
371,38.723
372,38.985
373,39.082
374,38.616
375,39.139
377,38.916
378,38.967
379,38.907
380,39.057
381,39.037
382,38.995
383,38.754
384,38.701
385,38.687
387,39.008
389,39.221
390,38.949
391,38.017
392,38.97
393,38.892
394,38.538
396,38.449
397,39.013
400,38.784
401,39.032
402,38.889
403,38.813
404,38.928
405,38.965
406,39.122
407,38.999
408,38.92
409,38.973
410,38.991
411,39.002
412,38.861
413,38.934
414,38.93
415,38.856
416,39.03
417,38.929
418,38.628
419,38.807
420,38.956
421,39.065
422,39.008
423,38.914
424,38.951
425,38.898
426,38.891
427,39.356
428,38.968
429,39.026
430,38.925
431,39.212
432,39.183
433,39.049
434,39.079
435,39.091
436,39.071
437,38.724
438,38.879
439,38.987
440,39.019
441,38.945
442,39.182
443,39.125
444,39.138
445,39.078
446,38.825
447,39.001
448,39.011
449,39.084
450,39.024
451,39.026
452,39.102
453,39.102
454,39.317
455,38.936
457,38.969
458,38.936
459,38.536
460,38.852
461,39.107
462,38.637
463,38.867
464,37.063
465,38.035
466,39.064
467,37.437
468,38.874
469,38.475
470,38.836
471,38.971
472,38.827
473,38.908
474,38.567
475,38.749
476,37.969
477,38.855
478,38.348
479,38.876
481,38.769
482,38.675
483,38.891
484,38.649
485,38.919
486,38.937
487,38.922
488,38.842
490,38.813
491,38.83
492,38.809
493,38.739
494,38.811
495,39.013
496,39.08
497,38.892
498,38.868
499,38.879
501,38.87
502,38.848
503,38.665
504,39.06
505,38.696
506,38.948
507,38.792
508,38.896
509,38.855
510,38.963
511,38.926
513,38.674
514,38.741
515,38.793
516,38.851
517,38.964
518,38.83
519,38.846
520,39.073
522,38.81
523,37.493
524,38.948
525,38.704
526,37.456
527,38.716
529,38.941
530,38.828
531,38.909
532,38.829
534,38.795
535,38.757
537,38.699
538,38.982
539,38.983
540,38.932
541,38.808
542,38.988
543,38.933
544,39.06
545,39.134
546,38.651
547,38.839
548,39.132
549,38.911
550,38.503
551,38.785
552,38.763
554,38.671
555,38.51
556,38.936
557,38.559
558,38.701
559,38.693
560,38.562
561,38.889
562,38.91
563,38.441
564,38.701
566,38.772
568,38.681
569,38.509
570,38.785
571,38.799
572,38.79
573,38.833
575,38.656
576,38.677
577,38.854
578,38.439
579,38.849
582,38.094
583,38.871
584,38.502
585,38.818
586,38.627
587,38.685
588,38.812
589,38.752
590,38.601

I just want to find a combination which has the minimum value of standard deviation.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: list the whole combinations than find min of combination is not the best way. Any help?

Comment: This code seem to already do what you want. What do you mean by "This code works, but not for the large amount of numbers"?

Comment: combination(120, 108) takes too many time and throws memory error.

Comment: This looks problem looks like it would be solved well by a genetic algorithm

Comment: Your distribution (X) is not normal/gaussian. However it does look (40.0 - X) could be well modeled with a log-normal, exponential or chi-squared distribution. Take a look at [the common probability distributions](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/common-probability-distributions-the-data-scientists-crib-sheet/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution that works for normally distributed data. The idea is that the subset of samples closest to the mean will be definition have the smallest standard deviation.

If your data is not uniform you could do k means clustering before hand and then check the desired number of points closest to each mean and see which of those subsets has the smallest standard deviation.

Note that the example data you provided only had 38 values, and they were in one line so I changed how `nda` was created from the dataframe

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('randint35-39.txt', header=None)
nda = df.values[0, :]

nda = nda[:113]
print(nda.shape)

# sort values by their distance from the global mean
normalised_vals = abs(nda-np.mean(nda))
indices = np.argsort(normalised_vals)
print(indices)

num_in_combo = 12

the_best = nda[indices[:num_in_combo]]

print("Global mean = {:10.3f} Global std_dev = {:10.3f}".format(np.mean(nda), np.std(nda)))
print("Subset mean = {:10.3f} Subset std_dev = {:10.3f}".format(np.mean(the_best), np.std(the_best)))

print(the_best)
```

Edit: things to do to improve this answer: use the median instead of the mean if you suspect big outliers. Use the the output of this to create a binary membership mask, create a population of randomly slightly changed masks and then use a genetic algorithm to get the best mask (using the standard deviation of the included samples as the fitness function). If the range of the samples is small then do a brute force search along the range and find the N samples closest to that (just like above) and see which point along the range gives the set with the lowest standard deviation

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will think about your solution for a while because of my fool about python. And I try the k-means solution from sklearn.cluster, but I can not confirm that the result from k-means is the best.

Comment: @jingzhang This is a classic dilemma. If you don't have any prior information about the problem to be optimised then the only way to be sure of having the global optimum is to do brute force. If you only need a good solution, but not the best, then statistical methods like this answer or local optimisation techniques can work.

Comment: Also for your problem, you can look at outlier rejection techniques if the set you want to keep is about 95% or more of the total

Comment: Thanks a lot to Spoonless! What I need is a solution and a result which can manually throw the outliers with a hist plot. I just want to save the time by using programming techniques. any example sent to me to learn from?

Comment: scipy d evolution may be the solution. I try to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jing. If you like my suggestions please upvote my answer. Or best of all Edit my answer with your results from Scipy evolution and that mark it as the accepted answer so other people can benefit too

Comment: I just voted your answer. Also I try the D Envolution for no answer. It is difficult to code the function for DE to minmize. Any Help?

Comment: @JingZhang I haven't used Scipy before to genetic algorithms or other evolutionary code (back in my PhD I wrote from scratch in C) and realistically I won't have time to figure it out before I go on vacation in a few days. So even though it looks fun, I won't be able to help in the next week or so, but see my comment on your histogram in the original post